# Return those records off some parents from which their children's certain property equals a certain value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

How to write this query? :

```
var parents = parents.Select(o => o.children.Where(p=>p.property1 == "Something")).ToList();
```

This comes up with the conversion type error. How can I return some parents based on a condition being true for their children's properties?

Comment: `Select` is for selecting items. You want `parents.Where`. Then you want a parent where *any* of its children match. Thus it becomes `parents.Where(... children.Any(...))`

Comment: why are not writing full code, like `var/or a type = parents.Select...` and also correct the missing `)` where do you want to put it?

Comment: @Anil Thanks. I edited the code.

Comment: @EfronA. thanks for the correction, but you should not be getting `conversion type` exception in the code in question, to selecting the list of where expressions `o => o.children.Where(p=>p.property1 == "Something")` to a var type. In case you really want to select parent then you should be selecting the parent after applying your filtering e.g. `Where(x->x..).Select(p->p)`, @Rob has already clarified this.

Answer (score 2):

This is what your query could be:

```
parents = parents.Where(p => p.children.Any(c => c.property1 == "Something")).ToList();
```

[Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) **filters** a sequence of values based on a predicate whereas [Enumerable.Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) **projects** each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Enumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx) would return true if there be at least 1 child with *porperty1* equal to "something"

As **all you need to do here is the filtering, you just need to use `Where`**. You would have used `Select` if you wanted to create a collection of some type other than that of the parent itself.

Comment: {<Internal Error evaluating expression>} This is what I would get. I have got a one to zero/many relationship and the property values could also be null for the children. Also p.children could also have null values since the relationship is one to zero/many as I said. Is this right? @sachin

Comment: Then you have to add a null check too. `parents = parents.Where(p => p.children != null && p.children.Any(c => c.property1 == "Something")).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try Code

```
var parents=    (from p in parents.AsEnumerable()
    where p.children!=null && p.children.property1 =="Something"
    select p).ToList()
```